# How do I turn the debug bar off in one view in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How do I turn the debug bar off in Yii2? I tried

```
<?php
use app\assets\AppAsset;
define('YII_DEBUG', false);
AppAsset::register($this);
$this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

But it gave an error `Constant YII_DEBUG already defined`. I don't want to turn it off for the whole app, just that view.

Tried `Yii::$app->modules['debug'] = null;` and got

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>   Indirect modification of overloaded property yii\web\Application::$modules has no effect

This executed, but the debug bar still shows.

```
$modules = Yii::$app->modules;
$module['debug'] = null; 
Yii::$app->setModules($modules);
```

Comment: check wheather this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560278/how-can-i-disable-yii-debug-toolbar-on-a-specific-view

Comment: Yep that worked! I wonder why it didn't come up in a search?